# Checking if first three elements of list are same data type.Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am begginer in Prolog.I have my custom types bird,fish,animal.So the problem is i want to pass function like firstThree([owl,eagle,chicken,cat,dog]). and 
get result true because first three are same data type.For another example:

```
firstThree([dog,cat,mouse,owl,shark,eagle]). > true

firstThree([shark,dog,owl,mouse]). > false
```

This is my base data:

```
bird(eagle).
bird(chicken).
animal(cat).
animal(mouse).
animal(dog).
fish(shark).
fish(wheal).
fish(goldfish).



isSameType(X,Y):- bird(X),bird(Y);animal(X),animal(Y);fish(X),fish(Y).
```

I have tried this but it doesnt really work:

```
firstThree([H1,H2,H3|T]):-
   isSameType(H1,H2),
    areSameType([H2,H3|T]).
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `isSameType/2` is working,

```
firstThree([H1,H2,H3|_]) :-
    isSameType(H1, H2),
    isSameType(H2, H3).
```

ought to be sufficient, because equality is transitive (if H1 = H2 and H2 = H3 then H1 = H3).

In the future it would probably behoove you to try something like:

```
critter_type(Critter, bird)   :- bird(Critter).
critter_type(Critter, animal) :- animal(Critter).
critter_type(Critter, fish)   :- fish(Critter).

isSameType(X, Y) :- critter_type(X, Type), critter_type(Y, Type).
```

Comment: But then they are all animals.

Comment: Right you are. .